# Mysterious email message

Tags: cipher

Today I found something quite interesting in my email.
An xml file with this puzzle:

> **`-|- |-| 0_ |\/| 0 0 |\| | § |_ | -|-`**

Can you solve it for me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

is it...

> The Moon Is Lit

Because

> the symbols look like letters
>   -|- is t
>   |-| is H
>   0_  is e
>   |\/| is M
>   0 is O
>   |\| is n
>   | is I
>   § is S
>   |_ is L

Comment: meh. beat me to it by a second. 
Albeit, the symbols used for the E are questionable, so I wonder if there's more to this..

Comment: Same, just beat me to it...I was thinking that *could* be a lower case e...but not the best

Comment: rot13(vg'f gur fznyy r cebqhprq ol n pvepyr naq n yvar: 0_ )

Answer (score 9):

> “tHe MOON IS LIt” written in l33+ speak, the computer text language where letters are replaced by numbers, symbols, and combinations of characters which form a resemblance to the shape of the letters. There might be a wiki page about it, try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet

Comment: Well I tried to answer first but came in second.  I like my spelling anyway.